# suggestion about how to adapt a function that wrap text in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am tring to wrap text in d3, I have read about it and I understand that the way to do it in d3 is to separate the long text into substrings which are inserted in `tspan` elmenets or by adding the text to the `foreignObject` element.

I am trying to adapt this function using the `tspan` method

```
function wrap(text, width) {
    text.each(function() {
        var text = d3.select(this),
            words = text
                .text()
                .split(/\s+/)
                .reverse(),
            word,
            line = [],
            lineNumber = 0,
            lineHeight = 1.1,
            y = text.attr("y"),
            x = text.attr("x"),
            dy = text.attr("dy"),
            dx = text.attr("dx"),
            tspan = text
                .text(null)
                .append("tspan")
                .attr("x", x)
                .attr("y", y)
                .attr("dx", dx)
                .attr("dy", dy);
        while ((word = words.pop())) {
            line.push(word);
            tspan.text(line.join(" "));
            if (tspan.node().getComputedTextLength() > width) {
                line.pop();
                tspan.text(line.join(" "));
                line = [word];
                tspan = text
                    .append("tspan")
                    .attr("x", x)
                    .attr("y", y)
                    .attr("dx", dx)
                    .attr("dy", ++lineNumber * lineHeight + Math.abs(dy) + "em")
                    .text(word);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

This function works properly but the coordinates defined in `dx` and`dy` of the text element are lost, so that the text appears in incorrect positions within the graphic.

I have identified that by replacing the `.attr("dy", ++lineNumber * lineHeight + Math.abs(dy) +" em ")` line with `.attr("dy", dy)` the text is placed in the desired position but the `tspan` elements overlap.

Getting this

[image]

I am new to the concepts of d3 and I appreciate your comments

Update 1: Distribution of tspan elements once called the function `wrap`

```
<g class="category">
    <circle r="15" cx="112.58330249197704" cy="64.99999999999997"></circle>
    <text x="112.58330249197704" y="64.99999999999997" dx="20" dy="10" text-anchor="start">
        <tspan x="112.58330249197704" y="64.99999999999997" dx="20" dy="10"></tspan>
        <tspan x="112.58330249197704" y="64.99999999999997" dx="20" dy="11">Third</tspan>
        <tspan x="112.58330249197704" y="64.99999999999997" dx="20" dy="11">Bit</tspan>
        <tspan x="112.58330249197704" y="64.99999999999997" dx="20" dy="11">Category</tspan>
    </text>
</g>
```

Update 2: Graph state after applying updated function, text distribution detail

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have been using this function for a while now, might work for you as well (maybe with slight adjustments):

```
function wrap(text, width) {
    text.each(function () {
        var text = d3.select(this),
            words = text.text().split(/\s+/).reverse(),
            word,
            line = [],
            lineNumber = 0,
            lineHeight = 1, 
            y = text.attr("y"),
            x = text.attr("x"),
            dy = 0,
            tspan = text.text(null).append("tspan").attr("x", x).attr("y", y).attr("dy", dy + "em");
        while (word = words.pop()) {
            line.push(word);
            tspan.text(line.join(" "));
            if (tspan.node().getComputedTextLength() > width) {
                line.pop();
                tspan.text(line.join(" "));
                line = [word];
                tspan = text.append("tspan").attr("x", x).attr("y", y).attr("dy", lineHeight + "em").text(word);
                lineHeight++;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

UPDATE: It looks like I copied the wrong function, I have multiple versions of it across my projects. I believe this one should work properly.

Your function has same issue as the first function that I shared had - we both were not increasing `lineHeight` (in your case it is called `lineNumber`) in the loop.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I have tried and unfortunately the text loses its coordinates and also overlap. At this moment I don't really know how to adjust the function

Comment: @user615274 It would really help if you could set up a working example somewhere so that I could take a look at your case.

Comment: I thought about it, but it is difficult for me, I am new to d3 and the graph is complex, and I have a hard time replicating a minimal functional version. In case it is relevant I have updated the question with how are the tspan elements distributed once called the function `wrap`

Comment: @user615274 could you please check out the updated code? I think this one should work this time, let me know if it still does not!

Comment: Thanks again for answering, it works better, with the function that I originally showed lost the coordinates of the text, the same thing happened with the previous version that you showed, with this version the coordinates are not lost, although there is still a detail with the distribution of the text. I update the question with a visualization of the graph, I detail the subject of the text. I know it's a lot to ask but if you get an idea how to solve it I will appreciate the advice

Comment: @user615274 At least you have y/dy coordinates working properly. Now you need to play a little bit with x/dx (I suggest you set dx=0 for the beginning) and also check 'text-anchor' style property: https://bl.ocks.org/emmasaunders/0016ee0a2cab25a643ee9bd4855d3464